# PHP - All queries execute twice in Chromium based browsers but only once in Firefox or Mullvad

Tags: php

I have a script file that gets called from an angular app, If I'm opening the App on chromium based browsers(Edge or Chrome) all of my queries (at least the `insert` ones) get executed twice but if I'm using [Mullvad](https://mullvad.net/en) or Firefox the query only executes once. I've even tried `Postman` and it only executes once.

Is there a way to fix it so that it only works once in chromium browsers?

here is a function in the code:

```
public function addTraitement($id,$nom,$date,$nomprenom,$Nom_Medecin,$Prenom_Medecin)
{
    $result;
    $con=connect();
    if($con!=null)
    {
        $con->query("INSERT INTO `traitement`( `id_Patient`, `Nom_Traitement`, `Date_de_Debut`) 
        values('".$id."','".$nom."',STR_TO_DATE('".$date."', '%d/%m/%Y'));");
        $con->query("insert into `historique`(`Nom_Patient`, `Nom_Medecin`, `Prenom_Medecin`, `Action`) 
        values('".$nomprenom."','".$Nom_Medecin."','".$Prenom_Medecin."','Ajouter Traitement')");
        $result = array("result" => "Success");
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
    else{
        $result = array("result" => "Failure");
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I suspect the problem does not lie within the PHP code you have shown here - but that code looks to be wide open to sql injection.

Comment: Go check what is happening in terms of HTTP requests, in the network panel of the browser dev tools. Most likely, Chrome is making the request that is triggering this, twice instead of just once. Once you have confirmed this, it is time to look at the client-side part of things, to figure out _why_ that request is happening twice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem, for some reason the preflight request executed my queries as well so I just added an if statement to check if it's a preflight request

I did

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'OPTIONS'){
//My code
}
```